# Beautifulsoup Website Scraper on Yahoo Table Symbols

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

i have problems to scrape the information i need from a website.

I want to add the symbols from the table on this site to my tickers: https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGDAXI/components?p=%5EGDAXI

But i don't know how to get the symbols.

I tried it with .select and the html class "class=C($linkColor) Cur(p) Td(n) Fw(500)" but it didn't not work.

I get this error but i think this means, it could not get the symbols..

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Marv/PycharmProjects/Screener/venv/Screener.py", line 45, in 
print(stocks2)
NameError: name 'stocks2' is not defined

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_analysts_info, get_stats, get_live_price, get_quote_table
import pandas as pd
import ssl


ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

url = 'https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGDAXI/components?p=%5EGDAXI'

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

data = defaultdict(list)

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    data["Symbol"].append(item.select('class=C($linkColor) Cur(p) Td(n) Fw(500)')[0].get_text())

tickers = data["Symbol"]

stocks = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Aktie', 'Volumen', 'Durchsch. Volumen', '2Volumen'])

for ticker in tickers:
    df = get_stats(ticker)
    df['Aktie'] = ticker
    df = df.pivot(index = 'Aktie', columns = 'Attribute', values = 'Value')
    df['Volumen'] = get_quote_table(ticker)['Volume']
    df['Durschn. Volumen'] = get_quote_table(ticker)['Avg. Volume']
    df = df[['Volumen', 'Durschn. Volumen']]
    df['2Volumen'] = df['Durschn. Volumen']*1.5
    df = df.reset_index()

    df.columns = ('Aktie', 'Volumen', 'Durchsch. Volumen', '2Volumen')

    stocks = stocks.append(df, ignore_index = True)
    stocks2 = stocks.loc[stocks['Volumen'] > stocks['2Volumen'], :]

print(stocks2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my browser there is no class `.simpTblRow`, if you need to select table row use selector `tr.BdT`.

`class=C($linkColor) Cur(p) Td(n) Fw(500)` is not valid (CSS) selector, you can use `a` instead and to select first element use `select_one`

```
data = {
  'Symbol': []
}

for item in soup.select('tr.BdT'):
    data["Symbol"].append(item.select_one('a').text)

stocks2 = []

for ticker in data["Symbol"]:
    stocks = stocks2.append(ticker)

print(stocks2)
```

Comment: When i try a other website where some Symbols do not have data i get a error message. Do you know, how i can fix this?

Comment: error from `get_quote_table()` ? it better to post another question.

Comment: its confusing... here is the error: `traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Marv/PycharmProjects/Screener/venv/Screener.py", line 35, in <module>
    df['Volumen'] = get_quote_table(ticker)['Volume']
    frame["adjclose"] = data["chart"]["result"][0]["indicators"]["adjclose"][0]["adjclose"]
KeyError: 'adjclose'` when i use this site: https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5ESDAXI/components?p=%5ESDAXI